# Efficiently building a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have multiple tables such as

```
[Item]          [Items_Categorys]                [Categorys]  [Item_SubItem]
-Id              -Id                             -Id          -Id
-Title           -Item_ID [FK: Item]             -Text        -Title
-Description     -Category_Id [FK: Categorys]                 -Item_Id [FK:Items]
-Image
```

So I want to make it where if they go into the Items/{item_id} page, it will add the item, its category's, its subitems etc into the view. I created a LocalModel where it holds IEnumerables of the Categorys, Subitems etc. My question what is the best way to order the linq sql query to get all this information at once. Currently, I'm just using a number of for statements for each table and storing them into variables and then putting those variables into my LocalModel to be sent to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have defined your class `Item` like below:

```
class Item
{
    .....
    public virtual ICollection<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

So, in order to load eagerly `SubItems` and `Categories`, you can use `Include` method:

```
var item = dbContext.Items.Include(i => i.SubItems)
                          .Include(i => i.Categories)
                          .SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id = id);
```

Also make sure you have:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

in order to use `Include` with lambda style.